# Opposite of "only-matching" in grep?

Tags: grep

Is there any way to do the opposite of showing only the matching part of strings in grep (the -o flag), that is, show everything except the part that matches the regex?

That is, the -v flag is not the answer, since that would not show files containing the match at all, but I want to show these lines, but not the part of the line that matches.

**EDIT:** I wanted to use grep over sed, since it can do "only-matching" matches on multi-line, with:

```
cat file.xml|grep -Pzo "<starttag>.*?(\n.*?)+.*?</starttag>"
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a rather unusual requirement, I don't think `grep` would alternate the strings like that. You can achieve this with `sed`, though:

```
sed -n 's/$PATTERN//gp' file
```

**EDIT** in response to OP's edit:

You can do multiline matching with `sed`, too, if the file is small enough to load it all into memory:

```
sed -rn ':r;$!{N;br};s/<starttag>.*?(\n.*?)+.*?<\/starttag>//gp' file.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a little help from `sed`:

```
grep "pattern" input_file | sed 's/pattern//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way in grep.

If you use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), you could output Perl's special variables $` and $' variables to show everything before and after the match, respectively:

```
ack string --output="\$`\$'"
```

Similarly if you wanted to output what did match along with other text, you could use $& which contains the matched string;

```
ack string --output="Matched: $&"
```